# read line of file in realtime in C

Tags: c, file, real-time

I know how to do basic file operations in C, but what I'd like to do if it is possible is somehow create a variable that represents a live running file (for example, an access_log from apache that updates every second). Then I want to be able to read the last line that is entered into the file as it happens regardless of whether any other process currently has the file open or not.

I'm thinking of code like this:

```
int main(){
  FILE *live=fattachto("/path/to/apaches/access_log");
  long lastupdated=live->lastwrite();
  while(1){
  if(live->lastwrite() != lastupdated){printf("File was just updated now\n");}
  sleep(1);
  }
}
```

Yes I did put in sleep in my code because I want to ensure my code doesn't oveheat the cpu.

and the code above as-is won't execute because I'm looking for the correct set of functions to use to produce the end result.

Any idea?

Comment: Plesae don't write code like this. Code is art, it's not suppose to just compile and work, this code is too ugly for me, I am never coming back to this question.

Comment: I think you're looking for the [`stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) system call.

Comment: The term "realtime" is one of the most missused and/or missunderstood terms. Please provide the definition **you** use. And on correct hardware and a correct OS an application would not be able to "overheat" the CPU.

Comment: @iharob Sorry for bad pseudo-c code but I'm trying to demonstrate what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to open the file and read the line when you need it, instead of keeping a variable updated? Why isn't this an option for you? Portable or linux-specific?

Comment: Maybe look into [inotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html)

Comment: I notice you don't update `lastupdated` in your `while` loop. Very wise to `sleep(1)` so as to keep the CPU cool!

Comment: sounds like you are trying to write `tail -f`. Why not use that or find its source code as a starting point ie http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/text_cmds/text_cmds-8.3/tail/tail.c

Comment: after being disappointed with cphulk's performance in blocking attackers on my server, I decide to write a very lean one for myself that takes very little resources.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set line buffering or use small buffer read size, once you've seeked to the end of the log file?  Then simply do blocking reads on the lines from the file as they're added?

Then when the read returns, you can signal, set flags or initiate processing, on any interesting input.